# Deployed Reactjs in AWS Amplify is removing the URL parameters the first time it loads

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services

I have a very simple ReactJS app deployed using AWS Amplify and it is removing the whole parameters section from the given URL the first time it loads. This is not happening on my local environment. I simulated a production environment on my local and it works fine.

For example, if I enter this URL: `https://deployed_url?param1=one&param2=two` the first time it becomes `https://deployed_url` the first time. After that `https://deployed_url?param1=one&param2=two` keeps these parameters.

I've been googleing for a possible solution, but I was unable to find any clue on how to solve this. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I've gotten into this problem. Currently, Amplify doesn't support URL params. The solution is to put a trailing slash before the parameter.

For example: `https://example.com/test/?id=123` instead of `https://example.com/test?id=123`

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console/issues/97#issuecomment-663103815

from here, you can copy `Redirects` for SPA.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html